# ~~ Access 2010 Forms VBA - Set Focus to Record on image click

Tags: ms-access, onclick, vba, record

I have a Form '*frm_doc_revs*' that has a control source set to a query I made: '*query_doc_form*'. I set this form with "*Default Vie*w" property to "*Continuous Forms*" Everything is working as expected **EXCEPT**

When I click on an image in a record I have an "On-Click" method that creates a hyperlink to a file and opens the path - **The problem is that I must first set focus to the record, THEN click on the image in order to get the correct path. If I just click the image, it does not place focus on the record**

**---> What I need is VBA code such that when the user clicks on an image in a record, the code places focus on that record first <---**

I'm at a loss here - any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Here's an image describing the situation a little better - My simple Click Methods are below

[image]

**VBA CODE**

```
Private Sub pdf_img_Click()
   Dim fname As String, fpath As String

   fname = Me.PDF_NAME
   fpath = "P:\Engineering\002 Engineering Data Base\Design Standards Database\pdf\" & fname

   MsgBox (fpath)
   'Application.FollowHyperlink (fpath)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, images don't set the focus to the record.

Easiest method: use a button instead, which has the image as `Picture` property.

If you don't like the look of that, create a **transparent button** (set the `Transparent` property to Yes) with the same dimensions as the image, and put it "above" the image.

Then move your code in the OnClick event procedure of the button.